# Whatsapp crashes when trying to share Image through ShareAction Provider

Tags: java, android, shareactionprovider

So, I first take the image from the drawable folder and then try to share the same through `ShareActionProvider` but Whatsapp (or any other app) keeps on crashing. It successfully sends the text but not an image. The image is in PNG format.

This is my Menu XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.android.shareactivity.ShareActivity">

<item
    android:title="share"
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    />
</menu>
```

This is my implementation of `ShareActionProvider`

```
public class Sharing extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sharing);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        //Share Action Provider
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

        if(mShareActionProvider!=null) {

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, R.drawable.untitled);

            // sharingIntent.setType("text/*");
            // sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hello World");
            mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sharingIntent);
        }

        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Beyond fixing the `EXTRA_STREAM` problem as noted in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50550962/115145), use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard. It is your data. You know what the actual MIME type is, so use that MIME type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, R.drawable.untitled);
```

You cannot pass a drawable which is inside your package to any other app, you will have to write this as png or jpg on the disk and then share the path of that file to whatsapp.

If your targetSdkVersion is 24 or above you will have to use file provider to share your file with any other app

Comment: Sharing the path will not work on Android 7.0+. Use `FileProvider` to share the content identified by the file that you create from the resource content.